# how can I set API data as inner html with lit

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element, lit

I have html element with lit

and I'm gonna set inner html of them
with get request

how can set them?

```js
import { LitElement, html, css } from "lit";
import { customElement } from "lit/decorators.js";
import axios from "axios";

@customElement("s-profile")
export class Profile extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`<p>${getProfile()}</p>`;
  }
}

// get data from api
async function getProfile(): Promise<string> {
  const username = window.location.pathname.replace("/", "");
  const result = await axios.get(
    `http://localhost:8000/api/getProfile?username=${username}`
  );
  const data: string = (<any>result).data.result.username;
  console.log(data);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetching asynchronous data in a lit-element web component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694623/fetching-asynchronous-data-in-a-lit-element-web-component)

Comment: `getProfile` is `async`. You need to display a loader in the meantime and update the data once you got it.

Comment: See here how to run code when the component is mounted: https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#connectedcallback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `updateRequest()`

```js
import { LitElement, html, css } from "lit";
import { customElement, property } from "lit/decorators.js";
import axios from "axios";

@customElement("s-profile")
export class Profile extends LitElement {

  @property({ type: Object })
  data = {};

  // get user data from api
  async getProfile() {
    const username = window.location.pathname.replace("/", "");
    const result = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:8000/api/getProfile?username=${username}`
    );
    const data: UserData = (<any>result).data.result;
    this.data = data;
    this.requestUpdate();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.getProfile();
  }

  render() {
    return html`<p>${this.data}</p>`;
  }
}
```